# How can I get 1 bootstrap column on larger screens to break to 2 on smaller screens and stacked on mobile?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

Here is the html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row fluid">
    <div class="nav clearfix">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 clearfix">
            <div class="hotel">
                <div class="hotel_img"></div>
                <h1>Accomodation</h1>
                <div class="bottom_border"></div>
                <p>
                    Perfect solution:
                    <span>hotel, apartment, hostel, guest house</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 clearfix">
            <div class="tour">
                <div class="tour_img"></div>
                <h1>Tourist Attractions</h1>
                <div class="bottom_border"></div>
                <p>
                    Search your favorite:
                    <span>restaurant, museum, hotel, attractions</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 clearfix">
            <div class="clearfix restaurant">
                <div class="restaurant_img"></div>
                <h1>Restaurants</h1>
                <div class="bottom_border"></div>
                <p>
                    You are hungry:
                    <span>chinese food, burgers, traditional foods</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 clearfix">
            <div class="event">
                <div class="event_img"></div>
                <h1>Events & Tickets</h1>
                <div class="bottom_border"></div>
                <p>
                    It's time to have fun:
                    <span>concerts, cinema, exhibitions</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 clearfix">
            <div class="coffee">
                <div class="coffee_img"></div>
                <h1>Coffee Shop</h1>
                <div class="bottom_border"></div>
                <p>
                    You must wake up:
                    <span>Starbucks, Filicori, Nescafe, Lavazza</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 clearfix">
            <div class="gov">
                <div class="gov_img"></div>
                <h1>Government</h1>
                <div class="bottom_border"></div>
                <p>
                    Must see:
                    <span>parliament building, district court, royal house</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It wont break, instead it just stays as 1 column and forces a scroll bar. 
I want it to look like
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3
4 5 6
and stacked on mobile. instead it stays 1 2 3 4 5 6 on any screen size. The code looks right to me, I'm not sure if something is stoping it from breaking or if I am just doing it wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: This code seems to work fine. Do you have any CSS that might be interfering?

Comment: If I do I'm not figuring it out. Thanks for checking it. I'll have to dig around the css

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you are importing the Bootstrap library. Your code as pasted won't do anything without it.
2. For the small screens, use `col-12` to get full width, and for the large screens, use `col-6` to get half width (side by side columns).

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
            <div class="hotel">
                <div class="hotel_img"></div>
                <h1>Accomodation</h1>
                <div class="bottom_border"></div>
                <p>
                    Perfect solution:
                    <span>hotel, apartment, hostel, guest house</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
            <div class="tour">
                <div class="tour_img"></div>
                <h1>Tourist Attractions</h1>
                <div class="bottom_border"></div>
                <p>
                    Search your favorite:
                    <span>restaurant, museum, hotel, attractions</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
            <div class="clearfix restaurant">
                <div class="restaurant_img"></div>
                <h1>Restaurants</h1>
                <div class="bottom_border"></div>
                <p>
                    You are hungry:
                    <span>chinese food, burgers, traditional foods</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
            <div class="event">
                <div class="event_img"></div>
                <h1>Events & Tickets</h1>
                <div class="bottom_border"></div>
                <p>
                    It's time to have fun:
                    <span>concerts, cinema, exhibitions</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
            <div class="coffee">
                <div class="coffee_img"></div>
                <h1>Coffee Shop</h1>
                <div class="bottom_border"></div>
                <p>
                    You must wake up:
                    <span>Starbucks, Filicori, Nescafe, Lavazza</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
            <div class="gov">
                <div class="gov_img"></div>
                <h1>Government</h1>
                <div class="bottom_border"></div>
                <p>
                    Must see:
                    <span>parliament building, district court, royal house</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I have it linked. I'll try your import method

Comment: that works well but I would like them to look [] [] [] [] [] [] on large screens not stacked until medium and small screens

Comment: Your original code was on the right track then. Use `col-2` to get 6 columns.